# Timer in background mode

Tags: ios, background, timer

As we know there are some limitations for applications which running in background mode.For example, the NSTimer doesn't work. I tried to write a "Timer" like this which can work in background mode.

```
-(UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier)startTimerWithInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval run:(void (^)())runBlock complete:(void (^)())completeBlock
{
    NSTimeInterval delay_in_seconds = interval;
    dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay_in_seconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    // ensure the app stays awake long enough to complete the task when switching apps
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier taskIdentifier = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

        completeBlock();

    }];

    NSLog(@"remain task time = %f,taskId = %d",[UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining,taskIdentifier);

    dispatch_after(delay, queue, ^{
        // perform your background tasks here. It's a block, so variables available in the calling method can be referenced here.
        runBlock();

        // now dispatch a new block on the main thread, to update our UI
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            completeBlock();
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:taskIdentifier];
        });
    });

    return taskIdentifier;

}
```

I called this function like this:

```
-(void)fire
{
    self.taskIdentifier = [self startTimerWithInterval:10
                                                   run:^{
                                                           NSLog(@"timer!");
                                                           [self fire];
                                                   }
                                              complete:^{

                                                  NSLog(@"Finished");

                                              }];

}
```

This timer works perfect except that there is one problem. The longest period for background task is 10 minute.(Please refer to the NSLog in startTimerWithInterval).

If there any way to make my timer work more than 10 minutes? By the way, my application is a BLE application, I set UIBackgroundModes to bluetooth-central already.

Comment: No, I don't think so.  You are not allowed to just arbitrarily run code in the background (otherwise morons would drain the battery in an hour).  Your background mode has a designated set of things it can do (I presume simply respond to BLE events).

Comment: I did some tests and I found:

1. I'm using 10s as interval.

After 10 minute, the run block is still being able to called although the remaining task time is 0. For example, I called a local notification inside the run block. The local notification can still be fired.

2. I'm using 640 (more than 10 min) as interval.

At 600 (10 min), the complete block is called. But at 640s my run block is still called.

I guess this means that my timer works as long as the running time of a single task is not more than 10 minutes.

And it seems has nothing to do with the UIBackgroundModes.